# How I can center circle progress bar in bootstrap and css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="http://www.cssscript.com/demo/circular-progress-bar-plain-html-css/css-circular-prog-bar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="progress-circle p10">
        <span>10%</span>
        <div class="left-half-clipper">
          <div class="first50-bar"></div>
          <div class="value-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-circle p20">
        <span>20%</span>
        <div class="left-half-clipper">
          <div class="first50-bar"></div>
          <div class="value-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-circle p30">
        <span>30%</span>
        <div class="left-half-clipper">
          <div class="first50-bar"></div>
          <div class="value-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I use bootstrap 3 and this [circle progress bar](http://www.cssscript.com/circular-progress-bar-plain-html-css/).
And I work to center 3 progress bar, but It continues to the left.
add the margin, but it occurs break layout in mobile web.
How can I center three progress bars?
I want to center 3 progress bar, and add text under 3 progress bar.

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJeJE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1:**

Use `display:inline-block` in progressbar class `.progress-circle`. and add `text-align:center` to parent `div`

```
.row{
    text-align:center;
}

.progress-circle{
    display:inline-block
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
.progress-circle{
    display:block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. and If I adjust progress bar space, I adjust `progress-circle`'s padding?

Comment: you did not  show css code for progress-circle. so i dont know what you tried.  but this is the best solution for solve  your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some of Bootstrap's grid classes to fix your layout, specifically `col-sm-4` and `center-block`. See demo below:

```css
/*https://github.com/jumpifzero/purecss-circular-progress-bar/blob/master/css-circular-prog-bar.css*/

.progress-circle {
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 20px;
   position: relative; /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
   padding: 0;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   background-color: #F2E9E1; 
   border-radius: 50%;
   line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.35em;
    left: 0.35em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 4.3em;
    height: 4.3em;
    background-color: white;
    content: " ";
}
/* Text inside the control */
.progress-circle span {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #53777A;
    z-index: 2;
}
.left-half-clipper { 
   /* a round circle */
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   position: absolute; /* needed for clipping */
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em); /* clips the whole left half*/ 
}
/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/
.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
   clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
.value-bar {
   /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/ 
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 0.45em solid #53777A; /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
   /*background-color: #4D642D;*/ /* for debug */
   box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */
.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
   /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
   background-color: #53777A;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
}
.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar{ display: none; }


/* Progress bar rotation position */
.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar { display: none; }
.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar { transform: rotate(4deg); }
.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar { transform: rotate(7deg); }
.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar { transform: rotate(11deg); }
.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar { transform: rotate(14deg); }
.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar { transform: rotate(18deg); }
.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar { transform: rotate(22deg); }
.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar { transform: rotate(25deg); }
.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar { transform: rotate(29deg); }
.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar { transform: rotate(32deg); }
.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar { transform: rotate(36deg); }
.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar { transform: rotate(40deg); }
.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar { transform: rotate(43deg); }
.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar { transform: rotate(47deg); }
.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar { transform: rotate(50deg); }
.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar { transform: rotate(54deg); }
.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar { transform: rotate(58deg); }
.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar { transform: rotate(61deg); }
.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar { transform: rotate(65deg); }
.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar { transform: rotate(68deg); }
.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar { transform: rotate(72deg); }
.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar { transform: rotate(76deg); }
.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar { transform: rotate(79deg); }
.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar { transform: rotate(83deg); }
.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar { transform: rotate(86deg); }
.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar { transform: rotate(94deg); }
.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar { transform: rotate(97deg); }
.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar { transform: rotate(101deg); }
.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar { transform: rotate(104deg); }
.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar { transform: rotate(108deg); }
.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar { transform: rotate(112deg); }
.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar { transform: rotate(115deg); }
.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar { transform: rotate(119deg); }
.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar { transform: rotate(122deg); }
.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar { transform: rotate(126deg); }
.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar { transform: rotate(130deg); }
.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar { transform: rotate(133deg); }
.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar { transform: rotate(137deg); }
.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar { transform: rotate(140deg); }
.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar { transform: rotate(144deg); }
.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar { transform: rotate(148deg); }
.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar { transform: rotate(151deg); }
.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar { transform: rotate(155deg); }
.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar { transform: rotate(158deg); }
.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar { transform: rotate(162deg); }
.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar { transform: rotate(166deg); }
.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar { transform: rotate(169deg); }
.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar { transform: rotate(173deg); }
.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar { transform: rotate(176deg); }
.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar { transform: rotate(184deg); }
.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar { transform: rotate(187deg); }
.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar { transform: rotate(191deg); }
.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar { transform: rotate(194deg); }
.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar { transform: rotate(198deg); }
.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar { transform: rotate(202deg); }
.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar { transform: rotate(205deg); }
.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar { transform: rotate(209deg); }
.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar { transform: rotate(212deg); }
.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar { transform: rotate(216deg); }
.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar { transform: rotate(220deg); }
.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar { transform: rotate(223deg); }
.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar { transform: rotate(227deg); }
.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar { transform: rotate(230deg); }
.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar { transform: rotate(234deg); }
.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar { transform: rotate(238deg); }
.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar { transform: rotate(241deg); }
.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar { transform: rotate(245deg); }
.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar { transform: rotate(248deg); }
.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar { transform: rotate(252deg); }
.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar { transform: rotate(256deg); }
.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar { transform: rotate(259deg); }
.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar { transform: rotate(263deg); }
.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar { transform: rotate(266deg); }
.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar { transform: rotate(270deg); }
.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar { transform: rotate(274deg); }
.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar { transform: rotate(277deg); }
.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar { transform: rotate(281deg); }
.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar { transform: rotate(284deg); }
.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar { transform: rotate(288deg); }
.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar { transform: rotate(292deg); }
.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar { transform: rotate(295deg); }
.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar { transform: rotate(299deg); }
.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar { transform: rotate(302deg); }
.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar { transform: rotate(306deg); }
.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar { transform: rotate(310deg); }
.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar { transform: rotate(313deg); }
.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar { transform: rotate(317deg); }
.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar { transform: rotate(320deg); }
.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar { transform: rotate(324deg); }
.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar { transform: rotate(328deg); }
.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar { transform: rotate(331deg); }
.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar { transform: rotate(335deg); }
.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar { transform: rotate(338deg); }
.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar { transform: rotate(342deg); }
.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar { transform: rotate(346deg); }
.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar { transform: rotate(349deg); }
.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar { transform: rotate(353deg); }
.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar { transform: rotate(356deg); }
.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar { transform: rotate(360deg); }
Contact GitHub API Training Shop Blog About
© 2017 GitHub, Inc. Terms Privacy Security Status Help
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="progress-circle p10 center-block">
            <span>10%</span>
            <div class="left-half-clipper">
                <div class="first50-bar"></div>
                <div class="value-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="progress-circle p20 center-block">
            <span>20%</span>
            <div class="left-half-clipper">
                <div class="first50-bar"></div>
                <div class="value-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="progress-circle p30 center-block">
            <span>30%</span>
            <div class="left-half-clipper">
                <div class="first50-bar"></div>
                <div class="value-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add margin right and left auto to your progress-circle class, like so:

```
.progress-circle {
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

This shouldn't break on mobile.